# Run older iOS version for Cordova app using Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova

I have an Cordova app in Visual Studio running in a virtual machine (Parallels Desktop). From VS I select a device and build the app and run it in the Simulator on my Mac. The problem is that I can't select iOS version in VS. So the app will always run the lastest iOS version (9.1). Is there a way to run older iOS versions? I have tried to install iOS 8.4 in the Simulator, but this version is not available from VS.